# iOS label is invisible during viewWillAppear, backing from a pushed view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a button with 2 icons and a label. The button has a different background color for .selected state. When I click the button, the button is selected and a new ViewController is pushed. I'm trying to mimic the behaviour of UITableViewCell.setSelected(animated:), so when the user backs out from the new ViewController I want the background color to animate. I use this:

UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { button.isSelected = false }

It works fine when I put it in viewDidAppear but it's a bit too late so I want it in viewWillAppear. Problem is when I do it from viewDidAppear, the label on my button starts as transparent. The icons are fine and static but the label will animate from transparent to its color. Why? How I can prevent this?

Here is a small demo:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myButton: MyButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myButton = MyButton()
        view.addSubview(myButton!)
        myButton?.frame.origin.x = 200
        myButton?.frame.origin.y = 200
        myButton?.addAction(.init { [weak self] _ in
            self?.myButton?.isSelected = true
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true)
        }, for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIView.transition(with: myButton!, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { self.myButton!.isSelected = false }

    }
    
//    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
//        UIView.transition(with: myButton!, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { self.myButton!.isSelected = false }
//
//    }

}
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
}

class MyButton: UIButton {
    
    let label = UILabel("Hahahaha", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 14), textColor: .black)

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        
        setBackgroundColor(color: .white, forState: .normal)
        setBackgroundColor(color: .gray, forState: .highlighted)

        setBackgroundColor(color: .gray, forState: .selected)

        addSubview(label)
        label.frame.origin = .init(x: 40, y: 40)
        
        

    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControl.State) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
            let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
        }
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    convenience init(_ text: String = "", font: UIFont? = nil, textColor: UIColor? = .black) {
        self.init()
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        sizeToFit()
        self.textColor = textColor
    }
}
```

Try backing out from ViewController2 , see label starts invisible. Now comment out the viewWillAppear and use viewDidAppear instead, the label starts black.

Comment: Adding subviews to `UIButton` is a bad idea... a ***lot*** is going on "under-the-hood." Add your label as a sibling view... and use constraints to keep it "attached" if needed.

Comment: This makes me sad. Now I have to create a wrapper UIView over a button instead. I tried it, you are right, it will work then. But if I do the transition on the wrapper it will give the same effect, it must be done on the button itself. Seems more like it's something to do with UILabel than adding subviews to UIButton.

Comment: Without knowing anything about how you're trying to implement this, or what your overall UI is, you *could* create a "wrapper view" -- but you don't necessarily need to.

Comment: Oh come on.. give us the answer already :D
Is there anything I can set on the UILabel? Can I solve this while keeping the label on the UIButton? Maybe if I use attributedText instead?

Comment: Posted an answer with one approach -- hopefully you can build on that for your actual implementation / usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach...

Stick with your `UIButton` subclass, but instead of adding the label as a subview of the button, add it as a **sibling** view -- meaning, it will be a subview of the same view of which the button is a subview.

We'll add that label to the view hierarchy in the button's `didMoveToSuperview()` function, and we'll use auto-layout to constrain it at `(40, 40)` relative to the top-left corner of the button - checking to make sure we only do so once.

Most of this code is your original code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myButton: MyButton = MyButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(myButton)
        myButton.frame.origin.x = 200
        myButton.frame.origin.y = 200
        myButton.addAction(.init { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.myButton.isSelected = true
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController2(), animated: true)
        }, for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard self.myButton.isSelected else { return }
        UIView.transition(with: myButton, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { self.myButton.isSelected = false }
    }
    
//  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
//      UIView.transition(with: myButton!, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { self.myButton!.isSelected = false }
//      
//  }
    
}
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
}

class MyButton: UIButton {
    
    let label = UILabel("Hahahaha", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 14), textColor: .black)
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        
        setBackgroundColor(color: .white, forState: .normal)
        setBackgroundColor(color: .gray, forState: .highlighted)
        setBackgroundColor(color: .gray, forState: .selected)
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        // even though this is being called AFTER
        //  we have moved to the superview
        //  we should safely unwrap it
        guard let sv = self.superview else { return }
        // if we haven't added the label yet
        if label.superview == nil {
            // add the label as a sibling to self
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            sv.addSubview(label)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
                label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            ])
        }
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControl.State) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
            context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
            let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
        }
    }
}

extension UILabel {
    convenience init(_ text: String = "", font: UIFont? = nil, textColor: UIColor? = .black) {
        self.init()
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        sizeToFit()
        self.textColor = textColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I like the idea! But won't be using constraints, I like just modifying a frame in layoutSubviews. I will use this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Set the color or state of the label to your desired animation start value in `viewWillAppear`. Then trigger the animation from within `viewDidAppear`.

Reason:
When the button is pressed and you initiate a navigation, the button is not highlighted anymore and neither is it selected anymore. Thus it returns to it's normal state.

Now you navigate back. `viewWillAppear` is called. It's name implies "the view will be shown in a moment, but it's *not visible yet*". So when you start an animation at this point, UIKit assume that even if it did animate something, it won't be visible to the user. (The view is not yet visible = animations on this view won't be seen either.) To save resources UIKit will ignore the animation.

So the solution is: set the button state early and then start the animation once `viewDidAppear` is called and UIKit will actually execute it.

Comment: But it's "normal state" is not having a white label? If I had icons on it like on my real case, the icons will not become white before the animation.

viewDidAppear is too late for me. If you try System Settings you can see what I'm trying to achieve, try navigating to Bluetooth settings (for example) then navigate back.